# SDL_mixer wont play sound Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, sdl, sdl-mixer

I can't get `SDL_Mixer` to play sound on the raspberry. The program compiles and builds OK, but all I hear is a short squeak (like static) and nothing.

Any ideas?

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Mix_Chunk *snd1 = NULL;
    Mix_Music *m = NULL;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong";
    }

    if(Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 1024) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Kunne ikke loade musikk";
    }

    snd1 = Mix_LoadWAV("bicycle_bell.wav");

    if(snd1 == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Fant ikke filen";
    }

    Mix_PlayChannel(-1, snd1, 0);

    Mix_FreeChunk(snd1);
    Mix_Quit();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should add `std::endl` or `std::flush` after each stream write. Your program might want to tell you something.

Comment: Done, but no messages.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The program terminated before the sound was playing.

When testing a simple:

```
while(Mix_playing(sound));
```

fixed it.